# Spring Generate domain objects based on a WSDL possible package conflict

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jaxb, spring-ws

I'm currently developing a web service client following this instruction on [spring website](http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/):

> The interface to a SOAP web service is captured in a WSDL. JAXB provides an easy means to generate Java classes from a WSDL.

So this tutorial is suggesting use of maven-jaxb2-plugin to generate java classes from WSDL. I have already implemented the web service **server** and it has its own package structure which is not similar to the client package structure.

In addition in pom.xml, I can ask maven to place the generated class files into a specific package (in this case hello.service):

```
<generatePackage>hello.service</generatePackage>
```

Now my question is: when JAXB is generating the java classes and placing them in the specified directory, Is there a way to modify the class package name of these classes to comply with client package structure?

Just to be more clear these classes have a package structure defined on the server side and now I am placing them inside a package in client side which may or may not match the server...

And where is the correct place to put this generated classes? I read in another article that it is not a good practice to place them in **src/main**?

Comment: I don't understood your problem. Can you add more information, or configuration that you used?

Comment: Put generated files in `${basedir}/target/generated-sources` or something similar.

Comment: @user1516873 thanks for your response. I do need to use this classes in my application (consuming the service). How can I access them when they are in target directory?

Comment: Run `mvn package` and after that mark `/target/generated-sources` as source files root in your IDE.